# How to get the section label from a label inside an enumerate-list?

Tags: cross-referencing

When I define a label inside an enumerate-list I get a reference to the item number.

Is it possible to get a reference to the section?

Example:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\newcommand\secref[1]{[section of label '#1']}%<-- I ask for this function.
\begin{document}
%Should be: The 2nd item point on page 3 is in section 2.3.1
The \ref{mylabel}nd item point on page \pageref{mylabel} is in section \secref{mylabel}

%Should be: The 2nd item point on page 3 is in section 2.3.1
The \ref{mylabel}nd item point on page \pageref{mylabel} is in section \ref{sec:mylabel}

\blinddocument%create some (sub)sections

\label{sec:mylabel}
\begin{enumerate}
\item point 1
\item \label{mylabel} here is a label
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Remark I: I don't want to replace `\ref` to show always the section reference. I want to have the choice to get the item reference or the section reference.

Remark II:
The 2nd sentence in my example shows the result I want. But I want to avoid the definition of the *help-label* `sec:mylabel`.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem... Thinking about it from the reader's perspective: how many such lists and references will you have? If there are a lot, then you might consider simply labelling the list using `label=(\thesection.\label*)` (loading `enumitem`) and then using a simple `\pageref`, or `\vref` (from `varioref`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emit two `\label` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\seclabel}[1]{{%
  \label{#1}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\thesection}%
  \label{sec:#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}

\begin{enumerate}
\item X
\item\seclabel{mylabel} Y
\item Z
\end{enumerate}

This is a reference to item~\ref{mylabel} in section~\ref{sec:mylabel}
on page~\pageref{mylabel}.

\end{document}
```

This gives

> This is a reference to item 2 in section 1 on page 1.

Of course, if `hyperref` is loaded, clicking on the link created by `\ref{sec:mylabel}` will take to the item in the `enumerate` environment.

Comment: Should there be an extra group around the replacement?  If another `\label` is made to the same numbered item then `\@currentlabel` will still have `\thesection` in it.

Answer (score 5):

[`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) is meant as an extension to the traditional 2-piece `\label`-`\ref` system provided by LaTeX which yields a (1) label and (2) page number. Instead it functions on so-called property lists that supports multiple references using the same label:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{allref}% Reference details stored in list 'allref'
\zref@newprop*{section}[??]{\thesection}% Create new 'section' property
\zref@addprops{allref}{section, page, default}% allref reference (or property list) has section, page and default
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1]{%
  \zref@labelbylist{#1}{allref}% Write allref list to .aux (using zref)
}
\newcommand{\myref}[2][default]{\zref@extract{#2}{#1}\zref@refused{#2}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item X
  \item Y \mylabel{mylabel}
  \item Z
\end{enumerate}

This is a reference to item~\myref{mylabel} in section~\myref[section]{mylabel}
on page~\myref[page]{mylabel}.

\end{document}
```

The above MWE provides `\mylabel` which functions just like `\label` and an accompanying `\myref` for `\ref`. If used as-is, `\mylabel{<label>}` is equivalent to `\label{<label>}` as is `\myref{<label>}` to `\ref{<label>}`. However, to yield the section number associated with `<label>`, use `\myref[section]{<label>}`. This extracts the property value stored in the list. It would be possible to add any number of additional properties that could be extracted.

One caveat with the above approach is that the label is stored at page ship out (for obvious reasons related to the asynchronous ship-out routine). And, values other than the `page` property may change between being `\mylabel`ed and being `\myref`ed. Some work has to be done to overcome this problem, possibly using a dual label.

Of course, one could also overwrite the meaning of `\label` and `\ref` itself to use this, but it would imply a global change.

Answer (score 2):

My approach was to redefine the `\label` command, to also create a reference of the same name prefixed by `sec:` against the current section counter via the use of `\refstepcounter{section}`, making sure to undo the `step` beforehand via use of the `\addtocounter{section}{-1}` command.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Redefine commands.
\let\oldlabel\label
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
         \oldlabel{#1}%
         \edef\@currentlabel{\thesection}
         \oldlabel{sec:#1}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Section A}
        \lipsum[2]
    \section{Section B}
        \lipsum[2]
    \section{Section C}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item Point 1
        \item Point 2\label{mylabel} here is a label
        \end{enumerate}
    \section{Section D}
        The \ref{mylabel}nd item point on page \pageref{mylabel} is in section \ref{sec:mylabel}
\end{document}
```

If you then wanted to create a command `secref` similar to `pageref`, then this is easy via:

```
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\ref{sec:#1}}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

By the same token, in the event that the book class is in use, could be extended further to include `chpref` for chapter references via:

```
%Redefine commands.
\let\oldlabel\label
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
        \oldlabel{#1}%
        \edef\@currentlabel{\thesection}
        \oldlabel{sec:#1}%
        \edef\@currentlabel{\thechapter}
        \oldlabel{chp:#1}%
    }
\makeatother
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\ref{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\chpref}[1]{\ref{chp:#1}}
```

Comment: If I use `\refstepcounter{chapter}` I reset the section counter. There should be a mechanism to remember the section number. Bit it is a nice idea.

Comment: Cheers, forgot about that @egreg had the right idea via `@currentlabel`, modified accordingly. My original mechanism was flawed, since section resets subsection, subsection resets subsubsection etc as you have correctly identified.

Answer (score 0):

@egreg's answer is great. But if you use package hyperref, the label for the section links to the theorem instead of the section title. My solution fixes this:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[hyperref]{waynemath}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1]{{%
  \label{#1}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\thesection}%
  \label{sec-redirect:#1}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\seclabel}{\label{sec-auto:\thesection}}
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\ref{sec-auto:\getrefnumber{sec-redirect:#1}}}

\begin{document}


\section{A}\seclabel{}
content

\section{B}\seclabel{}
content

\begin{enumerate}
  \item X
  \item\mylabel{mylabel} Y
  \item Z
\end{enumerate}


\section{C}\seclabel{}
See item \ref{mylabel} in Section \secref{mylabel} on page \pageref{mylabel}.

\end{document}
```

[image: The result of the latex code]