# Hyperref refer chapter and page in text

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsmath

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{something}
    \blindtext[1]

\chapter{something else}
\section{a section}
    This is the most important equation in this chapter
    \begin{equation}\label{important-equation}
        1=1
    \end{equation}

\chapter{chapter 3}
    As we have seen in Equation \ref{important-equation} in Chapter (REF-chapter-of-equation) on page (REF-page-of-equation), we have something important
\end{document}
```

What I would like to achieve is to be able to automatically substitute (and link) the correct chapter and the correct page in the output instead of `(REF-chapter-of-equation)` and `(REF-page-of-equation)`.

I would obviously like to do it also with other environments (`figure`s, `theorem`s, `definition`s), not just equations.

And last obvious thing, I would like to avoid to "manually link the chapter", because if I add a chapter at the beginning, or worse if I move the equation to another chapter, I then would have to re-enumerate everything and this looks like a vary bad move.

I already have a look at `hyperref` manual, but with no too much success.

I don't know if this is relevant, I use pdfLaTeX on TeXLive 2015 on Ubuntu machines. The solution has to work with [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Any help on how to achieve this, will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried with `varioref` ?

Comment: Nice! I didn't know. This seems to work for the page, so it answers half of my question. Do you know anything about the Chapter?

Comment: It is possible with `nameref`.
See : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/get-the-title-instead-of-the-number-of-a-referenced-chapter-section

Comment: Mh.. no, that is definitely not what I was looking for :) Using the counter is ok with me, but somehow what I would like to do is to "recover" it from the equation reference (definition, theorem or whatever), so that if I move the equation to another chapter the reference gets updated too (as it happens with equation's number, page and such)

Comment: If you want to be aware to transform your chapter into a section, you could also use `cleveref`. See : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109843/cleveref-and-named-theorems

Comment: This is nice, but it is not what I am asking :)

Comment: With the `nameref` package you are able to have the chapter name, right ? and with the `varioref` package, you have the chapter first page ?

So I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I never said that I want the chapter name... Quite the opposite in fact: "Using the counter is ok with me" (two comments ago). Probably I wasn't clear: What I want is to be able to use the counter of the Chapter an equation belongs to in a reference (or a theorem, definition, ...). So that if I move the equation to another Chapter, the `ref` gets updated too. I hope that now is more clear.

Comment: for the page you need `\pageref{important-equation}`. for chapter, I will see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to update `\chapter` and insert a regular `\label`. The structure should be something that you're not going to use elsewhere in the document, of course, since `\label`s have to be unique. I've chosen to insert `\label{chapter-\thechapter}`, which is similar to `\label{chapter-2}` in Chapter 2 if `\thechapter` is `\arabic{chapter}` (the defaut).

To insert this label, we redefine `\chapter` and use some [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/help) to extract it from the default equation number - (`\thechapter.\arabic{equation}`) within `\chapref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref,refcount}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\oldchapter\chapter
  \renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
    \clearpage
    \oldchapter{#1}% Regular chapter
    \label{chapter-\thechapter}% \label this chapter
  }
}

\makeatletter
\def\extract@chapter#1.#2\@nil{#1}%
\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{{%
  \edef\x{\noexpand\edef\noexpand\chapnum{\noexpand\extract@chapter\getrefnumber{#1}\noexpand\@nil}}\x%
  \ref{chapter-\chapnum}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{something}
\blindtext[1]

\chapter{something else}
\section{a section}
This is the most important equation in this chapter
\begin{equation}
  1=1 \label{eq:important-equation}
\end{equation}

\chapter{chapter 3}
As we have seen in Equation~\eqref{eq:important-equation} in Chapter~\chapref{eq:important-equation} on page~\pageref{eq:important-equation}, we have something important
\end{document}
```

The above solutions assumes you'll only use numbered chapters. However, if you're also using unnumbered chapters, then you can use the following redefinition of `\chapter`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\oldchapter\chapter
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
    \clearpage
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {\oldchapter*{#3}}% \chapter*[..]{...}
      {\IfValueTF{#2}
         {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}% \chapter[..]{...}
         {\oldchapter{#3}}% \chapter{...}
       \label{chapter-\thechapter}% \label this chapter
      }%
  }
}
```

The only difference is the conditioning on whether or not you use `\chapter` or `\chapter*`, together with the conditional placement of `\label`.

---

Another solution, not compatible with [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath): 
[`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) is an easy option for this as it allows the user to specify more than the single `\ref` value via "properties".

Below I've created a new property `chapter`, which stored `\thechapter`. Additionally, each `\chapter` command has been redefined to insert a `\label` to allow for an appropriate hyperlink. Finally, `\label` is also updated to store the current chapter its used within.

If you just want the chapter number, and not a hyperlink to the start of the chapter, then there is no need to redefine `\chapter` (...life would be easier).

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{zref,hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{chapter}{\thechapter}% Chapter property holds \thechapter

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\oldlabel\label
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
    \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{chapter}% Special label
    \oldlabel{#1}% Old label
  }%
}

\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \oldchapter{#1}% Regular chapter
  \oldlabel{chapter-\thechapter}% \label this chapter
}
\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\hyperref[chapter-\zref@extract{#1}{chapter}]{%
    \zref@extract{#1}{chapter}}}\x%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{something}
\blindtext[1]

\chapter{something else}
\section{a section}
This is the most important equation in this chapter
\begin{equation}
  1=1 \label{eq:important-equation}
\end{equation}

\chapter{chapter 3}
As we have seen in Equation~\ref{eq:important-equation} in Chapter~\chapref{eq:important-equation} on page~\pageref{eq:important-equation}, we have something important
\end{document}
```

Some related references:

- [Refer to theorems in previous chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57799/5764)
- [How to get the section label from a label inside an `enumerate`-list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114114/5764)

Comment: Nice! :D I'll give it a try now